# cycle function run once after all images load

Tags: jquery, initialization, cycle

I have images within a slide div which I would like centered. The function 'loaded' runs after each slide, is there a way to run the function once on all images?

```
    // start jQuery Cycle   
    .cycle({ 
         startingSlide: startSlide,
         // when using the next/prev links
     onPrevNextEvent: function(isNext, idx, slide) { 
        hasSlid = 1;
        window.location.hash = (parseInt(idx) + 1) + ""; 
        return false;
     },
     // when using the pager thumbnails
     onPagerEvent: function(idx, slide) { 
        hasSlid = 1;
        window.location.hash = (parseInt(idx) + 1) + ""; 

        return false;
     },
     timeout: 0, 
     fx: 'scrollHorz',
     next: '.cycle-next',
     prev: '.cycle-prev',
     speed: 200,
     after: loaded,

    });


function loaded(curr,next,opts) {

        $('.slide .image img').each(function(){

        var height = $(this).height();
        var width = $(this).width();

        $(this).css('margin-top','-' + height/2 +'px');
        $(this).css('margin-left','-' + width/2 +'px');

        $('img').animate({opacity:1},150)
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, call the loaded on the page load and not on the cycle after event:

```
$('body').on('load', loaded);
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to trigger it.
$(window).on('load', loaded) triggers the function but only for the first slide.